# Recommend class design in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns

I'm new to Objective-c. For learning purposes I'm trying to build something like a phonebook. So I'll have a class called Person that will have some properties (name, phone, etc).

Right now I'm not preoccupied about persistence. But, I need something to "hold" Person objects. So I thought about create a class called People, but I don't know how to design it, specially the NSMutableArray that will hold the objects.

What I did was:

**PERSON.H**

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
   NSString *name;
}
@property(readwrite, copy) NSString *name;
@end
```

**PERSON.M**

```
@implementation Person
@synthesize name;
@end
```

**PEOPLE.H**

```
@interface People : NSObject {
   NSMutableArray *peopleArray;
}
@property(readwrite, retain) NSMutableArray *peopleArray;
- (void)addPerson:(Person *)objPerson;
@end
```

**PEOPLE.M**

```
@implementation People
@synthesize peopleArray;
- (id)init {
   if (![super init]) {
      return nil;
   }
   peopleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] retain];
   return self;
}
- (void)addPerson:(Person *)objPerson {
   [peopleArray addObject:objPerson];
}
```

**PHONEBOOK.M**

```
...
Person *pOne = [[Person alloc] init];
pOne.name =@"JaneDoe";

People *people = [[People alloc] init];
[people addPerson:pOne];
```

When I try to use this code, I receive an error:_**method sent to an uninitialized mutable array object**.

So, since I'm a newbie, probably the way that I did isn't the best/correct one. So, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things wrong with your initialiser for people.  It should look more like this:

```
- (id)init {
   self = [super init];   // always assign the result of [super init] to self.
   if (!self) {
      return nil;
   }
   peopleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  // use init not retain.
   return self;
}
```

Comment: you should call [self release] before returning nil, otherwise you will be leaking a memory alloc'ed for a Person object. [Person alloc] makes a room in memory for storing an object. [[...] init] returns initialized object. If init returns nil then the Person *var will be nil and you will be unable to release it later because you will be sending a release to nil.

Comment: @Centurion: The only time the above piece of code returns nil is if `[super init]` returned nil.  In this case, there's nothing to release.  I could have put a check in to make sure if `peopleArray` was nil, I also returned nil, in which case `[self release]` would be appropriate.

Comment: I had this situation, and I needed to call [self release] before returning nil'ly self. You can try yourself: a) create a single view application project; b) add new class file c) override the initializer of that class by putting your code, and assign self = nil after self = [super init]; d) add YourClass *c = [[YourClass alloc] init] and [c release] in your root view controller viewDidLoad method. Run profiler with instrument leaks and you will see you are leaking a memory.

Comment: @Centurion: But in your example `[super init]` does not return nil.  The code in my answer only returns nil if `[super init]` returns nil.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not calling init on the NSMutableArray when you create your peopleArray. Try calling:

```
peopleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

instead. You need not retain it unless you say for instance, did this:

```
peopleArray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
```

For reasons why, see [the rules for memory management](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). These rules are very important for any iPhone or Mac developer to understand, and quite frankly, are simple enough that there's no excuse. :)

Answer (score 2):

In `People.m` you probably meant to write

```
peopleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

instead of

```
peopleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] retain];
```